# Fixing DKIM_SIGNED score from -0.1 to positive

Tags: email, spam

i've checked my domain email account with mail tester and i've got

-0.1        DKIM_SIGNED     Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily valid
This negative score will become positive if the signature is validated. See immediately below.

How can I make it positive, because I've got emails going to spam even my domain name is not listed in any of back lists and check score is 10/10. With email's language there are no problems too. But emails still goes to Gmail Spam box.

Here link to check my information:
[Result from mail tester](https://www.mail-tester.com/web-x1my9)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think, this is ok, as is decribed in test details

> This negative score will become positive if the signature is validated. See immediately below.

and below are two lines with positive score, so summary from DKIM check is +0.1